# Mule Proxy Authentication

Tags: mule, mule-studio, http-proxy, mule-component, mule-esb

I am new to Mule. I need to hit a webservice which is outside our company's network and trying to connect with proxy. I wrote a sample java program below which is working fine with proxy.

```
URL url = new URL("WEBSERVICE_URL")
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY, PORT));
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
     public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("USER", "PWD".toCharArray()));
        }
     };
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);        
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

The above sample code works fine. I need the same to implement in mule. I tried it in mule with proxy authentication in `proxy` tab of HTTP Connector configuration but I am getting `407 - Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing." You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.` error.

```
Mule -
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="WEBSERVICE_URL" port="PORT" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" tlsContext-ref="TLS_Context">
  <http:proxy host="PROXY" port="PORT" username="USER" password="PWD"/>
</http:request-config>
```

Am I missing any configurations? For configuring proxy authentication in mule, do we need anything other than providing details in proxy tab?

Comment: Have you put in details required in Authentication tab.Like type of authentication/credentials etc.?

Comment: No. Why is that required ? I just want to use proxy. So provided only proxy host, port, username and password details under proxy section. Under Authentication I have given protocol to none.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from Anypoint Studio? If thats the case, you may have to provide the Network Connections proxy settings and try this.

Comment: @jvas : No I am trying to export as zip and deploy to mule server.

Comment: Might be related to a proxy requiring NTLM authentication in an older version of Mule. Newer versions have better support for NTLM.